# SED multiple characters inside a getops

Tags: unix, sed, getopts

I'm trying to create a script that can use a command such as

```
script -c abcd test.txt
```

and it will get rid of any characters `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` inside test.txt.

This is the code I have so far:

```
while getopts ":c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    c)
      sed 's/'$OPTARG'//g'
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

But this only gets rid of "abcd" inside my file, not a or b or c or d, not acdb etc.
How do I make SED read the OPTARG as seperate characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tr` instead:

```
tr -d "$OPTARG"
```

will delete all characters in OPTARG.

Or if you insist on using sed, use character sets:

```
sed "s/[$OPTARG]//g"
```

Comment: Indeed. Otherwise it will fail if OPTARG contains spaces or other special characters that could affect `tr` or `sed` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the characters together so that they're a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
ross@ross-laptop ~> cat foo
agkdjbdefghijglkthdn

ross@ross-laptop ~> sed 's/[abcd]//g' foo
gkjefghijglkthn
```

Hope that helps.